# Support Vector Regression (SVR) plots no graph in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am using Python 2.7.15rc1 in *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*. I was trying to plot graph of Support Vector Regression but I dint get any output.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Generate Sample data
x = np.sort(5 * np.random.rand(40, 1), axis = 0)
y = np.sin(x).ravel()

#Add noise to targets
y[::5] += 3 * (0.5 - np.random.rand(8))

#create classifier regression model
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel="rbf", C=1000, gamma=0.1)
svr_lin = SVR(kernel="linear", C=1000, gamma=0.1)
svr_poly = SVR(kernel="poly", C=1000, gamma=0.1)

#Fit regression model
y_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(x,y).predict(x)
y_lin = svr_lin.fit(x,y).predict(x)
y_poly = svr_poly.fit(x,y).predict(x)

#Plotting of results
lw = 2
plt.scatter(x, y, color="darkorange", label="data")
plt.plot(x, y_rbf, color="navy", lw=lw, label="RBF Model")
plt.plot(x, y_lin, color="c", lw=lw, label="Linear Model")
plt.plot(x, y_poly, color="cornflowerblue", lw=lw, label="Polynomial Model")
plt.xlabel("data")
plt.ylabel("target")
plt.title("Support Vector Regression")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**python svm.py** outputs nothing.
Did I missed something to import? or we can not plot graph of this?
I am new to machine learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `%matplotlib inline` at the top of your code if you are running on Jupyter Ipython notebook. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045100/jupyter-ipython-what-does-matplotlib-inline-do/38127899) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline/43028034).

Otherwise, I copied your code and removed `matplotlib.use("Agg")` , it works for me on Ubuntu 18.04, matplotlib version 2.2.2. Can you specify which version you are using ?

Also here is the code,

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Generate Sample data
x = np.sort(5 * np.random.rand(40, 1), axis = 0)
y = np.sin(x).ravel()

#Add noise to targets
y[::5] += 3 * (0.5 - np.random.rand(8))

#create classifier regression model
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel="rbf", C=1000, gamma=0.1)
svr_lin = SVR(kernel="linear", C=1000, gamma=0.1)
svr_poly = SVR(kernel="poly", C=1000, gamma=0.1)

#Fit regression model
y_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(x,y).predict(x)
y_lin = svr_lin.fit(x,y).predict(x)
y_poly = svr_poly.fit(x,y).predict(x)

#Plotting of results
lw = 2
plt.scatter(x, y, color="darkorange", label="data")
plt.plot(x, y_rbf, color="navy", lw=lw, label="RBF Model")
plt.plot(x, y_lin, color="c", lw=lw, label="Linear Model")
plt.plot(x, y_poly, color="cornflowerblue", lw=lw, label="Polynomial Model")
plt.xlabel("data")
plt.ylabel("target")
plt.title("Support Vector Regression")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Python 2.7.15rc1, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and matplotlib : 2.2.2. I tried removing `matplotlib.use("Agg")` but I got error __tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable._ I am using putty to connect my machine and running _python svm.py_. Is this correct?

Comment: In your case it would be better to save you figure I think. I am not sure but some environment variable needs to be set to view the png generated.

Comment: In _/etc/matplotlibrc_  _backend      : TkAgg_ is only enabled, rest of all lines are commented. is that fine?

Comment: I think you need to use ssh with -X arguement to enable display forwarding. Something like ssh -X system-id

Comment: I think this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453188/matplotlib-display-plot-on-a-remote-machine

Comment: Getting `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display` `ImportError: No module named _backend_gdk`

Comment: What is the configuration of the remote machine ?

Comment: As per the link shared I need to install Xvfb which doesn't show output. But I need graph to be plotted.

Comment: It is a VM with 4GB RAM where I am running all this. I tried directly in VM terminal but still no luck.

Comment: I think you will have to save the plot using https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Comment: Thanks matplotlib.pyplot.savefig worked for me. But still I am thinking why output graph plot is not getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib can use one of several "backends" for producing graphs. Those backends do different things. In your case you specified `Agg` backend that is used to write PNG files:

```
matplotlib.use("Agg")
```

So the solution is to **remove that line** to use the default backend for your system or choose a backend that produces graphs on screen. You might these first:

```
matplotlib.use("GTK3Agg")
matplotlib.use("WXAgg")
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
```

See https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend for the complete list of backends.

Comment: I tried above backends but with these getting different different errors from matplotlib. @Sergey

Comment: Well, try all the backends. At least some should work.

Comment: I tried others as well like Qt but no luck. I installed dependency libs but still same.